# Why is tuple.index() similar in performance to list.index()?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a simple function that receives something that implements .index() and a list of characters to check for.

My assumption was that since strings and tuples are both immutable they would have similar performance (or at the least, tuple would outperform list). Instead, tuple seems equivalent to list. Why is that?

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from random import randint
from timeit import Timer


def check_index(st, guesses):
    for i in guesses:
        st.index(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_checks = 10
    lst = [n for n in ascii_lowercase]
    st = ascii_lowercase
    tup = tuple(lst)
    guesses = [ascii_lowercase[randint(0, len(ascii_lowercase)-1)]
               for n in xrange(num_checks)]

    def run_string():
        check_index(st, guesses)

    def run_list():
        check_index(lst, guesses)

    def run_tuple():
        check_index(tup, guesses)

    t2 = Timer(run_list)
    print "List", t2.timeit()
    t3 = Timer(run_tuple)
    print "Tuple", t3.timeit()
    t = Timer(run_string)
    print "String", t.timeit()
```

Sample runs (Python 2.7.6)

```
List 5.26431703568
Tuple 5.28769207001
String 3.16058015823

List 5.30263400078
Tuple 5.17412590981
String 3.17718791962

List 5.21962976456
Tuple 5.35261583328
String 3.22652792931
```

Comment: My guess: a `str` is an iterable where each element is a single character, but in `list` or `tuple` each element can be *anything*.  This could make `index` more easily optimizable for `str`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr:** String `index` calls have a lot of optimizations under the hood, and don't have to do "rich comparisons".  Both `list`s and `tuple`s *do* have to do them; mutability doesn't matter.

---

If you open up [`stringobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/21fb1767e185/Objects/stringobject.c#l1764), you can see that `index` calls `string_find_internal`, which calls `stringlib_find_slice`, which calls `stringlib_find`, which calls `fastsearch`.

`fastsearch` links to [this page](http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm) in its comments, check it out if you're interested.  It has some interesting bits on how [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) substring searching is implemented in python.  But that's not important in your 1-character substring search, which `fastsearch` explicitly special-cases:

```
    } else if (mode == FAST_SEARCH) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (s[i] == p[0])
                return i;
    }
```

Very tight loop, and tight loops are pretty dang fast in C.

Okay, that covers strings.  What about `tuple`s and `list`s?

It's far simpler this time; this is the loop that **both** types have to do:

```
for (i = start; i < stop && i < Py_SIZE(self); i++) {
    int cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(self->ob_item[i], v, Py_EQ);
    if (cmp > 0)
        return PyInt_FromSsize_t(i);
```

Instead of just checking equality with `==`, this loop has to do [`PyObject_RichCompareBool`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/c-api/object.html#PyObject_RichCompareBool) every iteration through the loop.  I won't get into the code in too many specifics (check out [`object.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0012d4f0ca59/Objects/object.c#l990) if you're curious), but essentially this has to do some type checking, then see if the types implement rich comparisons, then call that comparison function, check if it returned the `NotImplemented` singleton, and finally return the comparison.

So, that loop is the bulk of the work that's done in an `index` call, and both lists and tuples have to do it.  Strings get to cheat.

Answer (score 1):

`index` compares every element with the given object. Since tuples stores like lists python objects, the comparision takes the same time. Strings are faster, because comparing characters is faster than comparing objects.

Comment: are strings not objects also?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  I imagine that in the `index` method, Python internally handles the `str` as a character array (or some similar equivalent) because it knows the type of each object *must* be the same.  It cannot guarantee that for a `tuple` or `list`.  This is also how `numpy` give such large improvements over `list` operations.

Comment: @SethMMorton, I see so if I am storing like types in a list where I am comparing elements a lot I would get a good performance boost using something like array.array("f",...) instead  as the type is predetermined?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am not familiar with the standard library's `array` module (I was talking about `numpy` arrays, which are different), but yes that is the whole idea of having a container that limits you to only holding one type - you don't have to do time-consuming type checking.

Comment: Hmm, I tried an array from the `array` module, `array('c', ascii_lowercase)` and its slightly better then list but no where near string. Good to know though

Comment: @DanR `array` is a general container, but `str` methods are specific to `str`.  I am not surprised that `str` still wins, since I'm sure there are character-specific optimizations it can take advantage of that `array` cannot.

Comment: @SethMMorton. I just started using it today to optimise an  app I have to run on Android, I used cython with it , I will have to time the difference for interest.